# Format of SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a SharePoint list which I need to get in a format as shown below. 
[image: List format]

Is it possible through SharePoint? The number of columns I need in a row is 36.

I am using SharePoint online version. Please direct a way to solve this.

Comment: You can create 36 columns in a single list. Number of columns won't be a problem.

Comment: My problem is can I get 36 columns in a horizontal format in a sharepoint list?

Comment: Depends on how wide your screen is. If it does not fit, there will be horizontal scroll bars.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. By the way I did it. What I did was, I created a simple html form and added it as a web part to the list I created. And then to get my format, I added a js file as web part and it worked as I expected.